# Uploading files to Blob & getting error: C:\Program Files (x86)\IIS Express\

Tags: asp.net, azure-blob-storage

I tried to upload file to blob. But I'm getting error like this:

> "'C:\Program Files (x86)\IIS
>   Express\Nominative-Officers-Entry-Form-Stu.docx'."

I don't use HttpPostedFileBase in my code. I just pass object to my controller with files to be uploaded. Lease tell me what I'm doing wrong?
I want to know wt this line means :

> "blockBlob.Properties.ContentType = "

This is my code:

```
        public static SaveResponses CreateFile(Blob_Storage_Header docDetails)
    {

        string storageConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["StorageConnectionString"].ConnectionString.ToString();

        CloudStorageAccount storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(storageConnectionString);


        CloudBlobClient blobClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient();


        CloudBlobContainer container = blobClient.GetContainerReference("test2");


        ICollection<Blob_Storage_Details> BlobStorageDetails = docDetails.Blob_Storage_Details;
        if (BlobStorageDetails.Count > 0) {
            foreach (Blob_Storage_Details item in BlobStorageDetails)
            {
                string DocUUID = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
                CloudBlockBlob blockBlob = container.GetBlockBlobReference(DocUUID + item.Blob_Name);
                var fileName = Path.GetFileName(item.Blob_Name);
                //blockBlob.Properties.ContentType = item.ContentType;
                // Create or overwrite the "myblob" blob with contents from a local file.
                using (var fileStream = File.OpenRead(fileName))
                {
                    blockBlob.UploadFromStream(fileStream);
                }
            }
        }



        SaveResponses saveResponse = new SaveResponses();
        saveResponse.saveStatus = "true";
        saveResponse.messageType = "success";
        saveResponse.message = "File Create message"; 

        return (saveResponse);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

> "'C:\Program Files (x86)\IIS Express\Nominative-Officers-Entry-Form-Stu.docx'."

Based on your code, I ran it on my side, then I got the following error:

[image]

Remark: In development environment, you could add “<customErrors mode="Off"/>” within the system.web node in your Web.config file, then you could view the detailed errors.

According to this error, I checked and found the specified file path was not existed.
After some trials, I fixed the issue on my side. Please follow the descriptions below to check your code to see whether it works:

a) Please pay attention to the code “Path.GetFileName”, it returns the file name and extension of the specified path string (e.g. settings.job).
b) Make sure that the filename that is used in “File.OpenRead(fileName)” is an absolute file path and the file is existed in your environment.

> "blockBlob.Properties.ContentType = "

Azure Storage Client Library for .NET is based on Storage Service REST API, 
From the official document we could find that “blockBlob.Properties.ContentType” represents the MIME content type of the blob, the default type is application/octet-stream.

MIME is a way to identity files on internet according to their nature and format. For example, using the "Content-type" header value defined in a HTTP response, the browser can open the file with the proper extension/plugin. For more details about MIME, please refer to this link: http://www.freeformatter.com/mime-types-list.html